# spring attempt to inject @Autowired dependencies in a Mocked instance

Tags: testing, groovy, mocking, spock, spring-test

I have the following classes:
com.foo.pkgx:

```
@Component public class A {}

@Component public class B {
    @Autowired A a;
}
```

com.foo.pkgy:

```
@Component public class C {
    @Autowired B b;
}
```

I.E. dependency-wise: C -> B -> A

When executing the following spock Specification:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.foo.pkgy"])
class Config {
    def mockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    @Bean
    B b() {mockFactory.Mock(B)};
}

@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config)
class CSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    C c;

    def "sanity"() {
        expect: c
    }
}
```

The test fails initialization:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'c': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: com.foo.pkgx.B com.foo.pkgy.C.b; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'b': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: com.foo.pkgx.A com.foo.pkgx.B.a; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.pkgx.A] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I read this as "tried to wire A into B, but failed". I wasn't expecting B to undergo autowiring, as it is mocked.

Could someone shed some light?

Thanks!

Comment: the first thing that caught my eye, basically inner configuration classes in test are static. Try make the `Config` class static.

Comment: @borino I think in the example, it's not an inner class of a spock spec. It's two independent classes. Also, you can see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Mock of a class is a subclass generated by code-generation library, byte-buddy or cglib-nodep to name a few. It's a regular bean from Spring perspective. And once any bean is instantiated then at some point, Spring starts "introspection" of the bean by means of various `...BeanPostProcessors`. E.g. Autowiring is handled by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. This postprocessor works in such a way that each bean is [inspected](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7a77e83e1099d29fd68f1f0a94216bb1e3d5cec7/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L482) through the entire class hierarchy. So your `class B` is there with `@Autowired` field `A` and Spring tries to resolve this dependency with no luck.

The good news, however, is that there is a demand for such a feature of disabling autowiring on a per-bean basis. And looks like eventually, Spring team [will introduce it soon](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13043).

Meanwhile you can just mock `A` so that `B`'s dependency is resolved. Or you can just use interfaces for your components, instead of using just classes. I believe the latter is the best practice